# copy the files and folder and merge via shell script

Tags: linux, shell, replace, merge, copy

I have to copy and merge the files and folder in a folder1 to same files and same folder in a folder2.  It should merge the files via shell script linux.

```
FOLDER1 -> 
      FOLDERA-> A.TXT 
      FOLDERB-> B.TXT 
      FOLDERC -> C.TXT
```

THIS SHOULD REPLACE SAME FOLDER AND FILES IN FOLDER 2

```
FOLDER2 -> 
      FOLDERA-> A.TXT 
      FOLDERB-> B.TXT 
      FOLDERC -> C.TXT
```

Comment: just use `cp -R FOLDER1/* FOLDER2/`

Answer (score 0):

Use `cat` command

```
cat FOLDER1/FOLDERA/A.TXT FOLDER2/FOLDERA/A.TXT
cat FOLDER1/FOLDERB/B.TXT FOLDER2/FOLDERB/B.TXT
cat FOLDER1/FOLDERC/C.TXT FOLDER2/FOLDERC/C.TXT
```

or you can use `paste` command

```
paste -d" " FOLDER1/FOLDERA/A.TXT FOLDER2/FOLDERA/A.TXT
paste -d" " FOLDER1/FOLDERB/B.TXT FOLDER2/FOLDERB/B.TXT
paste -d" " FOLDER1/FOLDERC/C.TXT FOLDER2/FOLDERC/C.TXT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the copy command

```
cp -r source/* Destintion/*
```

or Sync command:

```
rsync -av /source/ /destination/
```